# Random numbers with different output

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

I've tried to random 20 numbers with different output, but it still contains same numbers.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){
    int arr[20];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int temp;

    temp=rand()%20;

    int x=0;



      while(x<20)
      {
          if(x==0)
          {
              arr[x]=temp;
              x++;
          }
          else
          {
                  for(int j=1;j<=x;j++)
                  {
                     do
                      {
                          temp=rand()%20;  
                      } while(temp==arr[x-j]);
                  }
                  arr[x]=temp;
                  x++;
           }
      }

      for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
        printf("%d. %d \n",i,arr[i]);
        }



}
```

Here's the output:

> 1. 10
> 2. 1
> 3. 6
> 4. 2     <-- repeated
> 5. 13
> 6. 19
> 7. 2     <--
> 8. 19
> 9. 4
> 10. 19
> 11. 14
> 12. 18
> 13. 12
> 14. 2     <--
> 15. 17
> 16. 15
> 17. 0
> 18. 1
> 19. 18
> 20. 8

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What the question is?

Comment: Consider starting with an array containing integers from 0 to 19 and using the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm, rather than building up the array by generating each element with values that aren't present in previous elements...

Comment: As @Thomas said, if you want to numbers in the range of 0 to 19 with no duplicates then start with those numbers and shuffle them.

Comment: Just edited the question to fix some typos (like wrong _"differen"_ instead of correct _"differenT"_ in the title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){
    int arr[20];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int temp;

    temp=rand()%20;

    int x=0;

    while(x<20)
    {
          if(x==0)
          {
              arr[x]=temp;
              x++;
          }
          else
          {
              int j;
              do
              {
                  temp=rand()%20;
                  for(j=0;j<x;j++)
                  {
                      if ( temp==arr[j] ) break;
                  }
              } while ( j < x );
              arr[x]=temp;
              x++;
           }
     }

     for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
       {
       printf("%d. %d \n",i,arr[i]);
       }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
...
vector<int> vec;
for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i) vec.push_back(i);

random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: Not re-implementing the wheel is great, but `std::random_shuffle` isn't so great - if you can use C++11, you should strongly prefer `std::shuffle` with an appropriate engine from <random> instead. `std::random_shuffle` is still allowed to be based on `rand()` internally (and often still is, for compatibility reasons), which means it inherits all sorts of exciting and subtle flaws.

@Stephan T. Lavavej gave a great talk at this year's Going Native conference that includes some discussion on this (see 23:30 or so): http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @DanBjorge Even though I like this approach, there are many things that may seem way too magical for a person who had not used them before. On the other hand, the implementation with `random_shuffle` is quite clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your loop

```
for(int j=1;j<=x;j++)
{
     do
     {
          temp=rand()%20;  
     }while(temp==arr[x-j]);
}
```

Take for example the position when x=8. This will loop through j=1 to j=7. It will keep generating a number until it's not the same as the current number being checking in the array until the start of the array is reached. However, consider when j=7 is reached. When a new number is generated it may not be the same as the first element in the array, so the do-while loop will be exited; but, it may still be the same as other numbers in your array?

You need to (for each element): generate a random number. Check it doesn't match any of the numbers in the array. If it does start again, if it doesn't set the array number and continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a `std::vector` storing unique numbers in your desidered range, then shuffle it using `std::shuffle()`.

Note that [`rand()` is considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), so you may want to use a better pseudo-random number generator, like Marsenne Twister engine `std::mt19937`.

Compilable commented code follows:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::shuffle
#include <iostream>     // for std::cout
#include <random>       // for std::mt19937, std::random_device
#include <vector>       // for std::vector
using namespace std;

vector<int> PrepareUniqueRandomNumbers(const int count) 
{
    // Prepare the vector with unique numbers 0,1,2,...,(count-1)
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        numbers.push_back(i);    

    // Use Mersenne Twister engine as pseudo-random number generator
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 prng(rd());

    // Shuffle the vector, so the numbers
    // appear in a (pseudo-)random order.
    shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), prng); 

    return numbers;
}

int main() 
{
    const auto numbers = PrepareUniqueRandomNumbers(20);
    for (auto x : numbers)
        cout << x << '\n';     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a vector if you already know that you will store only 20 numbers. The rand() function is obsolete and not really good C++ style. You also do not need the Mersenne-Twister as engine for your intentions, that is absolutely not necessary.

```
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 20> randomNumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::default_random_engine engine(randomDevice());
    std::shuffle(randomNumbers.begin(), randomNumbers.end(), engine);
}
```